# conflict graphql multi queires using react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, ecmascript-6, graphql

I will try my best to describe the problem I am facing:

1-  I am developing one iOS app in which the first window shall make 4 different queries from different tables.

First section : sliders

Second : category

Third : designers (which are users)

Fourth : celebrities (which are different type of users with role celebrity)

First image showing the whole thing in sequence as I described above.

[image]

2- I am trying to fetch all queries needed in just one component like the following image

[image]

3- After the view is loaded... notice that the data are mixed meaning the celebrity (fourth section) is mixed with the data for (third section) 
please notice the second element of the forth section is repeated from the third row.

I cannot figure out what I did wrong but I am 100% sure the data is coming in the **graphql** server 100% correct.

[image]

Comment: just to add to ur knowlege i am using normal ids coming from sql db. meaning ids = 1, 2, 3, not very unique ids like firebase and non sql dbs. maybe this is the problem ? !! hope someone can help me with this

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what you mean by the data being "mixed". You seem to be referring to a picture or a code snippet that isn't actually there.